# Neo4j HA Enterprise Master/Slave control

Tags: neo4j, high-availability

When starting up Enterprise Neo4j in HA the 1st server is starting as the master.
I have a requirement where I want to control who the master is in the cluster, is that actually possible in Neo4j?
What would happen if I set all the slaves with 'ha.slave_coordinator_update_mode=none'.  Will this permit me to have a single master, and if it goes down no other instance will become the master, and when that instance recovers will become the master again.
Or, if I didn't use that setting, the master goes down and a slave takes over, when the original master comes back up will it just act as a slave or will it become the master again?
Is there some configuration that will permit control of that, the documentation doesn't cover that very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Orlok,

You can use ha.slave_only to ensure an instance doesn't ever become master. See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/ha-configuration.html

That effectively allows you to add as many read slaves as you wish, but beware that you lose high availability if you only have one instance that can become master. I.e. have a few instances master-ready, setup with ha.slave_only=false, as well as a bunch of read slaves.

Regards,

Lasse